# Ag-grid angular Vs material table

Tags: angular-material, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular-material-table

Which is better to use for rendering large amount of data with better performance, ag-grid or angular material table?
I'm trying to render 70,000 to 1,50,000 of data. I will also be performing certain operations like sorting filtering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have used both of them. So, I can confidently say that Ag-grid is much better than material table as it is very easy to use and efficient as well, but make sure that whatever features you are planning to use are available with community edition. Otherwise you need a license for enterprise edition features.

For more details of ag-grid, you can checkout this url: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/licensing/